# Lifting commutative diagrams of functors from the homotopy level to the "higher" level

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, dg-categories

Let $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ be differential graded categories over a field. Let $F, G, K : \mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ be quasi-functors (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178123/a-general-theory-of-quasi-functors-generalizing-from-dg-categories-to-mathcal) for definitions). Assume you have morphisms of quasi-functors: $\alpha : F \to G$ and $\beta : F \to K$. Then, assume that there exists $\overline{\gamma} : H^0(G) \to H^0(K)$ such that $\overline{\gamma} H^0(\alpha) = H^0(\beta)$ as natural transformations of (linear) functors $H^0(F) \to H^0(K)$. Then, is it possible to lift $\overline{\gamma}$ to a morphism of quasi-functors $\gamma : F \to K$ such that $H^0(\gamma) = \overline{\gamma}$ and $\gamma \alpha = \beta$? In general, I think the answer is *no* (who assures that a lift of $\overline{\gamma}$ even exists?), but perhaps it is true in some "well-behaved" cases. For instance, take $\mathcal A = \Delta^1$, the category with objects $0, 1$ and morphisms freely generated by a single arrow $0 \to 1$. Then, the $H^0(-)$ functor
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{rep}(\Delta^1,\mathcal B) \to \mathrm{Fun}(\Delta^1, H^0(\mathcal B))
\end{equation}
is full and reflects isomorphisms. Moreover, in this case, $\mathrm{rep}(\Delta^1,\mathcal B)$ is the dg-category $H^0(\underline{\mathrm{Mor}} (\mathcal B))$, where $\underline{\mathrm{Mor}} (\mathcal B)$ is the dg-category of morphisms as defined by Drinfeld in [this work](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0210114). Perhaps the answer is *yes* in this particular case.

Also, if you prefer the simplicial framework, just replace $\mathcal A, \mathcal B$ with $(\infty,1)$-categories, and study the functor
\begin{equation}
h \mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal A,\mathcal B) \to \mathrm{Fun}(h\mathcal A, h\mathcal B),
\end{equation}
taking $\mathcal A = \Delta^1$, the standard 1-simplex. I think that the above question can be asked, mutatis mutandis, in this setting.